# misalignment problem about newenvironment

Tags: environments, alignment

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newenvironment{mypro}{\begin{proof}\hfill\par\noindent}{\end{proof}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mypro}
    1\\
    2
\end{mypro}
\begin{mypro}%
    1\\
    2
\end{mypro}
\begin{proof}
    \hfill\par\noindent
    1\\
    2
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

and I get [image: that]
You can see it's out of alignment where i mark. But if i add "%" after "\begin{mypro}", it's ok. I want to know the reason of this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use `\noindent\ignorespaces` instead of `\noindent`.

Answer (score 2):

The second example shows where the problem is: the endline after `\begin{mypro}`. Add `\ignorespaces` at the end of the “begin” part.

But I suggest two further changes: to add an optional argument and also a “nonpage-breaking line break” (you don't want “Proof” to be at the end of a page and the test in the next one).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newenvironment{mypro}[1][\proofname]
  {\begin{proof}[#1]\mbox{}\\*\ignorespaces}
  {\end{proof}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mypro}
    1\\
    2
\end{mypro}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might also patch `\proof` and use the `proof` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\ignorespaces}{\mbox{}\\*\ignorespaces}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
    1\\
    2
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to add a simple explanation.

A line break is interpreted as a space. If you add a `%`, you comment out the line break, hence the space. You can see that with

```
A
B
C

vs. 

A%
B%
C
```

So, if you define your own environments or long defs, you should terminate every line with a `%`.